# Como generar una lista a partir de un input en Python

Tags: python

Estimada comunidad, necesito de su ayuda.

Estoy haciendo un programa de calculo con variables de entradas ingresadas por el usuario;

Ejemplo:

```
print ('Ingrese el grado del polinomio: ')
grado=input();

Si el usuario ingresa, por ejemplo el numero 4. Debo generar el siguiente menú:

print ('Ahora ingrese los coeficiente para cada variable: ')

a1= 

#Cuando presiona enter, debería pasar guardar ese valor y preguntar el siguiente coeficiente:

a2=

y así hasta: 

a3=
a4=
a5=
```

Luego al final debera general una lista, por ejemplo

```
varin = ( 'a1 a2 a3 a4 a5')
```

Agradezco, aun soy nuevo en Python. Ya leí algunos métodos, pero no los entiendo aún.

Answer (score 0):

Esto se resuelve con un ciclo for, donde preguntara el coeficiente en cada iteracion en el rango del grado del polinomio, aparte es mejor usar el input directamente.

```py
#obtenemos el grado del polinomio
grado = int(input("Ingrese el grado del polinomio:"))

"""
input nos devuelve un string por lo que si queremos operar con el, de forma aritmetica, tendremos que convertirlo a entero
"""

#aqui se almacenaran los coeficientes
variables = []
#hacemos el ciclo necesario
for i in range(grado):
     coef = int(input(f"ingrese el coeficioente para la variable N°{i+1}:"))
     #añadimos el coef a la lista
     variables.append(coef)
```

**Imprimimos**

```py
print(variables)
#[1, 1, 2, 3, 4]
#si quieres tenerlo como texto
variables = [str(v) for v in variables] #convertimos cada valor a string
variables = ",".join(variables) #lo unimos por una ','
print(variables)
#1,1,2,3,4
```

**Nota**
Los datos almacenados se almacenan como entero